# How to restart an array row count in a loop macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying figure out how to restart a row count in an small array function each time the do loop macro restarts. The first macro copies a series of formulas down the spread sheet until a criteria is met. Then once the criteria has been met, the second macro is supposed to start over and retype out the formula.

This is the VBA macro I have written for the array formula:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=SMALL(IF(Pivot!C3=R[7]C[-2],ROW(Pivot!C3),""""),ROW(R[-7]))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
```

Here are the formulas that appear as the macro loops.

First row:

```
=SMALL(IF(Pivot!$C:$C=H8,ROW(Pivot!$C:$C),""),ROW(1:1))
```

Then in the sixth row where the macro re-starts the loop, this is the formula that appears:

```
=SMALL(IF(Pivot!$C:$C=H13,ROW(Pivot!$C:$C),""),ROW(6:6))
```

I need the formula to change back to `ROW(1:1)`.

Here is the entire nested loop.

```
 Do
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Matrix!R10C1:R1048576C14,13,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Matrix!R10C1:R1048576C14,13,0))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[2],'GBS Data'!R8C5:R1046427C17,2,0)),""Not in GBS"",(VLOOKUP(RC[2],'GBS Data'!R8C5:R1046427C17,2,0))))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Matrix!R10C1:R150C14,14,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Matrix!R10C1:R150C14,14,0))="""",R[-1]C,VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Matrix!R10C1:R150C14,14,0))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=SMALL(IF(Pivot!C3=R[7]C[-2],ROW(Pivot!C3),""""),ROW(R[-7]))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-8]="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C12,0)))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-10]-"""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C12,0)))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-12]="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC8,'GBS Data'!C5:C41,R1C12,0)))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-14]="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Matrix!R10C14:R10000C15,2,0))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-14]=""Not in GBS"",""Not in GBS"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Pivot!C1:C5,5,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Pivot!C1:C5,5,0)))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-18]="""","""",COUNTIF('GBS Data'!C3,'Product Summary'!RC8&'Product Summary'!R1C24))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-22]="""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(RC8)&TRIM(R1C)&TRIM(RC20),'GBS Data'!R8C4:R1048576C41,13,0)),"""",IF(RC[-22]="""",VLOOKUP(TRIM(RC8)&TRIM(R1C)&TRIM(RC20),'GBS Data'!R8C4:R1048576C41,13,0),SUMIF('GBS Data'!C3,'Product Summary'!RC8&'Product Summary'!R1C24,'GBS Data'!C16:C[-8]))),SUMIF('GBS Data'!C3,R8C8&R1C24,'GBS Data'!C16))"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -20).Range("A1:U1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16) = ""

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

Loop Until Range("H1").Value = "Stop"
```

Comment: You need to post more of the code to get a proper answer.  We need to know what trigger restarts the loop.  Have you used variables before?

Comment: The loop is triggered to restart once a formula returns a zero.  I will add the entire nested loop to the posting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a bit of explanation on what the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) actually does. The [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) takes an integer as its second parameter. This signifies *how small*; essentially *smallest, second smallest, third smallest, etc*. The `ROW(1:1)` formula becomes ROW(2:2), ROW(3:3), etc as it is filled down. The result is *1, 2, 3, etc* which fulfills the *first, second, third, etc* for returning the sequential values from SMALL.

So to reset the ordinal value returned by ROW, all that is needed is a little maths. If we add the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) around ROW-1 and supply a divsor of *6*, we will get close. In fact we will get a series of numbers *0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5* that repeats itself. All we have to do is add *1* to get a series of numbers from *1* to *6* that repeats itself.

Put the following into any unused cell and fill down.

```
=MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 6)+1
```

That should produce a series of numbers like *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.* Applying that to your formula and the formula becomes,

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
  "=SMALL(IF(Pivot!C3=R[7]C[-2],ROW(Pivot!C3),""""),MOD(ROW(R[-7])-1, 6)+1)"
```

The first row using the formula should be,

```
=SMALL(IF(Pivot!$C:$C=H8,ROW(Pivot!$C:$C),""), MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 6)+1)
```